# Delete video option is not available in summernote

Tags: summernote

I am using one Summernote where i have option to add video url after adding video url video is showing in summernote, But there is no option present if user don't require video.[image: This is summernote added video image]

After adding video there is no option to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Placing the cursor just after the Video and hitting the Backspace button will delete the video entirely from your summernote code.

I expect you've found the solution already.